# Embed one pdf into another pdf using PyMuPDF

Tags: python, python-3.x

In need of help from learned people on this forum. I just want to embed one pdf file to another pdf file. So that when I go to the attachment section of the second file I can get to see and open the first file. I would like to do this with help of `PyMupdf`. Got a command `embeddedFileAdd` to do so but I am not sure how to use it.

Comment: Where is the code?

Comment: Actually I do not have one. Since I do not know how to do it. Sorry I am a novice.

Comment: Just Solved it:   import fitz
pdf1=r'C:\Users\Amit PC\Desktop\pdf1.pdf'
pdf2=r'C:\Users\Amit PC\Desktop\pdf2.pdf'
outfile=r'C:\Users\Amit PC\Desktop\test2.pdf'
img= bytearray(open(pdf2,'rb').read())
doc1=fitz.open(pdf1)
doc1.embeddedFileAdd(img,'attach.pdf')
doc1.save(outfile, deflate = True)
doc1.close()

Comment: Then share the answer:)

Answer (score 0):

**Just Soved it with this code:**

```
import fitz
pdf1=r'C:\Users\Amit PC\Desktop\pdf1.pdf'
pdf2=r'C:\Users\Amit PC\Desktop\pdf2.pdf'
outfile=r'C:\Users\Amit PC\Desktop\test2.pdf'
img= bytearray(open(pdf2,'rb').read())
doc1=fitz.open(pdf1)
doc1.embeddedFileAdd(img,'attach.pdf')
doc1.save(outfile, deflate = True)
doc1.close()
```