# How to attach/ embed a file to a PDF document using Python code?

Tags: python, pdf, attachment

I have 200 question papers and their marking schemes in PDF. I want to attach marking schemes to their respective question papers by using Python codes.

Example.

Question paper:

https://papers.gceguide.com/A%20Levels/Chemistry%20(9701)/9701_m19_qp_12.pdf

Marking scheme:

https://papers.gceguide.com/A%20Levels/Chemistry%20(9701)/9701_m19_ms_12.pdf

I am looking for a Python code to add the marking scheme to the question paper as an attachment.

Marking scheme is shown in the attachments area on the left side in this snapshot

https://i.stack.imgur.com/96zex.png

Comment: Please review this posting that may be helpful:[Embed one pdf into another pdf using PyMuPDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54839374/embed-one-pdf-into-another-pdf-using-pymupdf)

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me after little modifications.